# Laying out many divs horizontally but for lower rows to fill in tight below first row

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to layout a grid of div's (they contain image and text) of varying size. I'd like them to flow from left to right but for the lower ones to come in tight below the higher items. I'm having a hard time describing this to I've included a drawing of what I'd like to achieve, the numbers represent the order of the divs.
[image]

I've seen this in use and it appears all the divs are placed using absolute positioning.

Does anyone know how this layout can be achieved? I'm attempting to build a site that will work on web/tab/phone so the solution should be able to work across all platforms.

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/ - not sure about pure css solution, but this makes life easier.

Comment: As nevermind said above, use masonry. It is by far the best option for this.

Comment: Check the isotope by metafizzy.
The [fitColumn](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/fitcolumns.html) layout seems to fit for your plan

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just make column divs and put the images in accordingly? (images 1, 5, and 9 would go into column-1 div, and so on...)

Comment: "nevermind" if you write that up as an answer I'll tick it off. Works like a charm!

Comment: I'm not sure if this might be a solution for you: http://jsfiddle.net/9rrm1z83/

Answer (score 0):

This answer was supplied by **user:nevermind** but people keep adding comments so I'm going to write it up.

a JS plugin called **masonry** allows me to achieve the desired result.
it can be found here: [masonry.desandro.com](http://masonry.desandro.com)

after including the js file I followed HTML integration as shown on their website as:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item w2">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  ...
</div> 

<div id="container" class="js-masonry"
  data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 200, "itemSelector": ".item" }'>
```

I was acutlly using Drupal Views to generate my code, so I overrode my view by creating a template override file `views-view--myviewname.tpl.php` to include a `js-masonry` class reference. and altered the `.item` to look for `views-row`.

Works like a charm.